# Why I am getting NullReferenceException while accessing the div in code behind in the user control

Tags: c#, user-controls, nullreferenceexception

I added a div to the user control. But when I am trying to access the div in page_load method in code behind, I am getting NullReferenceException.

```
<div id="divCOVIDQuestion" runat="server"></div>
```

and in page_load method

```
divCOVIDQuestion.Visible = Client == "FI";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: No. I understand the NullReferenceException, but I don't understand why the div is getting null.

Comment: I am not familiar with C# browser bindings, but perhaps you need to use something like JS would? `Document.GetElementById( "divCOVIDQuestion" ).Visible`